# Why does android.opengl.Matrix.translateM() produce unexpected result?

Tags: java, android, matrix, opengl-es-2.0, matrix-transform

From the [sources](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/opengl/java/android/opengl/Matrix.java) of `android.opengl.Matrix.translateM(float[] m, int mOffset, float x, float y, float z)`:

```
/**
 * Translates matrix m by x, y, and z in place.
 * @param m matrix
 * @param mOffset index into m where the matrix starts
 * @param x translation factor x
 * @param y translation factor y
 * @param z translation factor z
 */
public static void translateM(
        float[] m, int mOffset,
        float x, float y, float z) {
    for (int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++) {
        int mi = mOffset + i;
        m[12 + mi] += m[mi] * x + m[4 + mi] * y + m[8 + mi] * z;
    }
}
```

The question is about this line (or the entire for-loop):

```
m[12 + mi] += m[mi] * x + m[4 + mi] * y + m[8 + mi] * z;
```

Why x, y and z components of translate parameters are multiplied to the source matrix components here? Shouldn't it be simple this (this lines replace the entire for-cycle):

```
m[12 + mi] += x;
m[13 + mi] += y;
m[14 + mi] += z;
```

---

**Background of the problem**:

I am doing some 2d game in OpenGL ES 2.0. I whant to scale and move some object there. While I simple move it:

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, x, y, 0);
```

all goes fine. As soon as I do scaling before moving - at this time moving translations:

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
Matrix.scaleM(mModelMatrix, 0, xScaleFactor, yScaleFactor, 1);
Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, x, y, 0);
```

are in fact multiplied by scaling :(

Comment: I am not sure, should this question be asked here or on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL is column-major, the proper order for Scaling, Rotation and Translation is actually `Translation * Rotation * Scaling`. In D3D and any row-major matrix library, `Scale * Rotate * Translate` would be correct. You have to think about things from right-to-left when you use column-major matrices.

Alternatively, you could transpose each matrix before multiplication - it is usually simpler just to follow the canonical order for column-major matrix multiplication though. Note that this applies to things like `Position * Model * View * Projection` (D3D / row-major) as well, in GL (column-major) the proper order is `Projection * View * Model * Position`.

Answer (score 1):

`translateM` *simulates* matrix multiplication of `m` X `T`, where `T` is a translation matrix.

A translation matrix is like an identity matrix (diagonal 1's) with a last column of  *x,y,z,1* for the translation. (The *1* is for homogenous coordinates which I won't go into).

Assuming you know matrix multiplication (where each row of the first operand is pair-wise mutliplied by each column of the second operand), it takes short-cuts by exploiting the specifics of a translation matrix `T`:

It doesn't actually create the translation matrix `T`, but *simulates* the multiplication `m x T`. Most of the values don't change (because of the part like an identity matrix), so it need only calculate the values that do change (involving the last column of `T`).

Each loop iteration pair-wise multiplies one row of `m` by the last column of the translation matrix (which is `x,y,z,1`). The line of code would be (with *i* being the row of `m` and column of `T`):

```
m[12+i] = m[0+i]*x + m[4+i]*y + m[8+i]*z + m[12+i]*1f;
```

but they simplify it with the `+=` operator; use `mi` for offset; and omit `0+`.

Elements that don't change can just be left there, because this version of `translateM` is "in-place",.

Bear in mind it uses matrices in **column-major** form, with indices:

```
0  4  8  12
1  5  9  13
2  6  10 14
3  7  11 15
```

As you step through the array, you go down through each element in a column, and at the end of it go across to the next column, etc. So the element at row *i* and column *j* is at `m[i + 4*j]`. That is, going down is *+1* and going across is *+4*. thr next  (The other way is **row-major**, where you go across a row, the down to the next row etc. More intuitive for printing, but not what `android.opengl.Matrix` uses.)

---

Your  `scaleM` then `translateM` is equivalent to `S x T` (scaling matrix `S`, translation matrix `T`). The effect is right-to-left (i.e. backwards), of the translation first and then the scaling. So, the translation also gets scaled.

As the accepted answer says, doing `translateM` then `scaleM` (i.e. `T x S`) has the effect of scaling then translating (so the translation isn't scaled).

One way to think about this is that this matrix will eventually be multiplied by a column vector `v`: `(T x S) x v`. Beginning differently, with `S x v = v'` scaling `v`, and then translating that result with `T x v'`, we could combine them as `T x (S x v)`. It seems natural that the scaling must be first. Perhaps surprisingly, because matrix multiplication is *associative*, it is the same as `(T x S) x v`. If we ignore the last `x v` (which is done on the GPU), we have `T x S`, which means "scale, and *then* translate". The matrix closest to the right is done first.

BTW The associativity of matrix multiplication is like java string concatenation, where the order of evaluation doesn't matter, where `(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)` (though the order of operands *does* matter, e.g. `a+b+c != c+b+a` - neither is *commutative*). This means we can whichever part first that suits us.

---

BTW: there are several layers here: matrix multiplication, the effect of ordering, homogeneous coordinates, translation matrix, effect of multiplication ordering, column-major form, the above multiplication short-cut, `+=`, and `mOffset,`mi` (for many matrices in one array).

Much of programming can be understood as you go along, but for this, it's better to get on top of each layer in turn.